# Minimizing size of largest group after K cuts

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, computational-geometry, graph-theory, plane

> Consider an  N x N  square of integers which you are allowed to cut
>   vertically or horizontally K times. You want to try to minimize the
>   largest sum in each of the resulting boxes after cutting. Print out this largest sum.

---

> Bonus: print out the arrangement of cuts that gives this lowest sum.

---

> Hint: Use bit manipulation

For instance, given that you are allowed 2 cuts and the grid is

```
1 0 1 4
1 0 1 0
1 2 1 4
```

By cutting it like so:

```
1 0 1 | 4
1 0 1 | 0
---------
1 2 1 | 4
```

You can minimize the maximum sum in any of the four quadrants, and you would print out 4.

---

The first thing I note is that given a maximum of K cuts, it is to your advantage to use up all K cuts.

One thing I thought of was binary searching for cutting positions to minimize the sum on each left/right half and then binary searching for top/bottom, but how would you extend this to more than 2 cuts?

The hint of bit manipulation also leads me to think some dynamic programming using bitmasks is the intended solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: @PhamTrung N <= 15 and K <= N so I'm guessing even brute force might work

Answer (score 1):

One observation is that, the order of the cut is not affected the final result.

So, using bit mask, we can check every combination of horizontal and vertical cuts.

Assume that we have a number with N - 1 bits, represented for all the horizontal cuts, and, if bit at position `ith` is one, so, it also means that we made a cut between row `ith` and `i + 1`th.

Similarly, we can have a number to represent all vertical cuts. From these two numbers, we can calculate the maximum sum of each area defined by those cuts.

Code to illustrate my solution.

```
for(int i = 0; i< (1<< (N - 1)); i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < (1 << (N - 1)); j++)
      if(number of bit set i + j == k)
         calculate the maximum sum;
```

Comment: For calculating the sum in each region based on the cuts, I assume you would pre-process the matrix using a data structure allowing for 2D range queries?

Comment: @1110101001 As N <= 15 and K <= N, this will not work, 2^30 is too large for this. Using condition `(i + j == k)` smartly can reduce the time complexity to C(2n, n), which is still too large. I will think of a way to improve this.